# How to display print dialog in java fx and print documents (not just nodes)

Tags: java, printing, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to print a generated pdf file in a java fx but all the examples I have seen are for printing java fx nodes. I could have used the ordinary printing api but the print dialog it shows is swing based and is like a totally different application in both behaviour and appearance, which may confuse users.

I'd like to show a dialog prior to printing so that users can choose their preferred printer and also change page setup if possible. According to [the open jdk wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Printing+for+JavaFX)  this was expected in java 8

> 1) PrinterJob - the class that controls the printing process  and
>   provides support for
>   *  print and page setup dialogs which will be
>   the platform native dialog
>        at least on Windows and Mac OS X.

and [the related jira issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17383) is marked as fixed

However this `PrinterJob` class and the javafx print package has two issues(as far as I can tell):

1. It prints only nodes.
2. No clear way of displaying a dialog for users to choose printing attributes

So how can I provide a printing dialog in java fx to help users print pdf documents?

**PS:** I'm using Java 8 update 20 in a desktop environment (Windows 7 64 bit)

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: OK, I filed a jira issue requesting the javafx print dialog feature here [https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38367](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38367) please vote for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java8 you can print only Nodes (as far i know).
But you can create an ImageView that renders an image you can print.
If you want to print an pdf take a look at https://www.idrsolutions.com/javafx-pdf-viewer or any other javafx PDF viewer.

You can render the pdf in a Node (PDF Viewer) and print this.

But if you want an Printing Dialog, I think you must build your own.

But thats not realy hard.

You can use all the Information given from the Printer classes for example:

```
    ObservableList<PaperSource> paperSources = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    paperSources.add(PaperSource.AUTOMATIC);
    paperSources.add(PaperSource.BOTTOM);
    ...

    PrintQuality.values()
    PrintSides.values() 
    ...
```